# how to browse securely from behind home router using openssh?

Tags: ssh

i have seen a lot of explanations on setting up a ssh tunnel from work to home and vice versa. i am trying to do something hopefully a bit easier. i have an old macbook pro running 14.04 as a single boot system. i have loaded openssh server on it and i am just trying to use it to browse securely with firefox. do i have to have a machine on either side of the ISP router for this to happen? i work remote. therefore my 'work' office is also behind the ISP router. lots of ssh setup details on the net, just nothing like this. thank you for any advice.

Comment: Can you elaborate a lot on "to browse securely". What exactly is the goal?

Comment: thank you. yes. to browse securely i mean by using ssh and an alternate (to my isp) dns server to browse/download, etc. in other words, i don't need anyone looking at my traffic.

Comment: Why not just use Tor?

Answer (score 0):

There will be *always* someone looking at your traffic (unless you will use `tor`). If it will not be your home ISP, it will be your work ISP or IPS for your server in some server-housing company. It is mostly statistical information about traffic to optimize the links, but they can also search for patterns, for example copyrighted content.

You can encrypt point-to-point communication to prevent this happening using ssh and for example SOCKS proxy, but when you will leave this link, you will get to the internet and it can be only on different place. Later on internet you will need to use something that servers support and it is usually HTTPS (there is a plugin that tries to enforce it, called [HTTPS Everywhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/https-everywhere/))

Comment: Thanks. I am not interested in using tor. Am just interested in seeing if anyone can answer my question. I'll rephrase the question: how do you set up an SSH tunnel from the server behind the ISP to the Internet across the ISP?. I suppose I could just turn my phone on and turn my Wi-Fi off and I would have an endpoint external to my local network

Comment: if you watn to set up tunel, you need to know where does the tunnel. You can't tunnel just to "internet". But if you have server with public IP, you can set up SOCKS proxy using `ssh -D localhost:9999 public_ip` and set up Firefox or global proxy to use SOCKS proxy on `localhost:9999` (the last option)

Comment: thank you. how do i set up a public ip address for my ssh_server behind the ISP router?

Comment: you need to have one (to buy, borrow from internet company or something) and there is pretty much only few left. But this is certainly different answer than the original so if you have another question, please fill new one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your home computer is accessible from the internet (you have an external, real IP) and you want to use SSH to tunnel all your connections from office, there is a brief list of to-do's.

In brief:

1. Make a port forwarding entry (NAT) on your router to the computer that will run OpenSSH inside your home network. (from 0.0.0.0:22 to  serverip:22)
2. Setup OpenSSH server on your computer. Configure it by editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Make sure you restart server to apply changes using `sudo service sshd restart`
3. When you see that your SSH is running (run `sudo netstat -nlp | grep 22` you should see an entry), check that the port forwarding works from the outside using, i.e service such as ping.eu.
4. Run a SSH session from work to home. You have to open a local dynamic port (`ssh -D` option): `ssh -D 65530 john@home`. See `man ssh` for details.
5. Setup your browser (or any other application) to use localhost:65530 as proxy for connections.
6. There you go.

Comment: 1. done. 2. done. 3. done. 4. recall that my 'work' machine is behind the ISP router on the same lan as the server...

Comment: If you have the client on the same LAN as the server, you will only secure traffic from the other LAN clients, but not the internet.  Otherwise, there is not point of setting up the tunnel. You either use VPN or TOR, or get a dedicated IP as advised below and complete the setup similar to what i've and @Jakuje has advised.

Answer (score 0):

No need for any of the command line stuff. Easy solution. Pulled an old Galaxy 3 android out of the drawer with no sim. Plugged it in. It's the server. Downloaded android ssh server. Much easier setup than open ssh. Works beautifully.